# parallelize beautiful soup scraper in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, parallel-processing, beautifulsoup

I would like to parallelize my scraping script, which in written in python using beautiful soup. Despite reading up on it, I am confused on how to get it to work in my code. 
What I want to do for now is take a list of links as input and open several browsers/tabs to take this urls as input. Later obviously I want to include my entire code and scrape from each of the sides. But I cannot get this first step to work.

Here is my attempt:

```
Test_links = ['https://www.google.com/maps', 'https://www.google.co.uk/? 
gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=3vPNWpTWOu7t8weBlbXACA', 'https://scholar.google.de/']

def get_URL(Link):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
    browser.get(Link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    pool.map(get_URL, Link)
```

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing with this code? Is it only opening one browser/tab?

Comment: Im am getting this error message: 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value

TypeError: get_URL() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: I think there's an issue with (Link) as your parameter for get_URL. It's expecting that there are no arguments for get_URL, but it looks like you map Link to it.

Comment: Yes, so Link should actually be Test_links here. So how do I get get_URL to expect the argument Test-links, because that is obviously what I need to call on the URLs?

Comment: Check out my answer below, I think it might be an issue with your naming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I think there's an issue with your naming. Try to stay away from capitalizing variables, because I think they are getting confused with Objects. You could try something like this to see if that theory is right.

```
test_links = ['https://www.google.com/maps', 'https://www.google.co.uk/? 
gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=3vPNWpTWOu7t8weBlbXACA', 'https://scholar.google.de/']

def get_URL(test_links_list):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
    browser.get(test_links_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    pool.map(get_URL, test_links)
```

I'm not sure if browser.get() will take a list, you might have to iterate over the list calling browser.